# What are your favourite places to rent an apartment in Mallorca?

Tags: international-travel, spain

Can anybody recommend a great place ? I will spend 14 Days in July and would like to rent an apartment close to the sea!

Comment: I assume you are asking about 'booking' an apartment, not 'buying' an apartment?

Comment: yes sorry it was a mistake :-)

Comment: I have been second-home prospecting in Mallorca. My experience is that you really need to get into the interior before finding anything reasonable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This site is different from normal web forums, in that questions that will primarily inspire opinion or personal preference are not allowed. Rather, this site is for questions about facts, that can be answered in a concise way. For this question, your best bet would be to find a travel *forum* or a travel agent. On Stack Exchange, you could discuss such a matter in [chat], but you need 20 reputation first.

Answer (score 1):

We like Porto Petro a small mallorquin fishing village with a small harbour only 5 minutes from one of the famous beaches "Cala Mondrago" away. We have rent a apartment with a local agency Inmobiliaria Porto Petro [here](http://www.mallorca-properties.co.uk/en/)

Hope that help!!

Comment: Is Porto Petro close to Cala dor?

Comment: Yes just 10 minutes with the car or with the public train!!